# Is the list method .append() a mutator?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a question that I am stumped on, I am reviewing for a midterm and have this question:

The list method .append() is a mutator.
TRUE or FALSE.

The correct answer is TRUE according to the answer key but why? what is a mutator?

Comment: Is Google down again?

Answer (score 1):

Python objects can either be mutable (changeable) or immutable. Lists are mutable, therefore any method which acts on a list to change it could be called a mutator.

Answer (score 0):

Mutator means that is changes the object. It's another name for setter method.

Comment: "Mutator" and "setter" are not synonymous. Setters are a subset of of mutators.

Answer (score 0):

A *mutator* (also called a *setter*) is method of an object that allows you to modify some of its variables in a controoled way, following the principle of encapsulation.

For example, if you have a variable called `age` storing the age of a user, you'll want to perform some checks on it to make sure that nobody changes its value to things like `-35` or `Pi`. You would then make that variable private, meaning that you can't modify it directly, and you'd then need to use a *mutator* that will checks for the validity of the new value. Such a method could be called `setAge`, for example.

Here, a list is a Python object, but, because of its complex implementation, users can't directly modify the memory. You have to use the method `append()` to add an item to the list. Therefore, this method is a mutator.

Comment: most of this has nothing to do with Python

Comment: He asked what a mutator is. I couldn't really explain it from scratch